# How to extern SDL_Surface array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, sdl

I want to extern a `SDL_Surface` array from one function (`load_level`) to another (`initialize_balls`). I have to say that the `SDL_Surface` (`brickim`) is a dynamic pointer-struct which is defined inside of `load_level` function via `malloc` function and declared as `SDL_Surface **brickim` as well. I got a segmentation fault when I try to access `brickim[0]->w` in the `initialize_balls` function but not in the `load_level` function. This is the piece of code I hope you could help me to fix.

file1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
SDL_Surface **brickim; /*as global*/
SDL_Surface* load_map(char *map_name , int tran );

void load_level(int stage){
int n;
SDL_Surface **brickim=( SDL_Surface **)malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface)*input.N);
    for (n=0;n < input.N;n++){
        **brickim[n]=load_map("brick1.bmp",1); /*load SDL_Surfaces*/**
        printf("%d\n",brickim[n]->w);  /***access succesfully (returns 100 N times)***/
        }
...
}}
SDL_Surface* load_map(char *map_name , int tran ){
SDL_Surface *temp,*map;
Uint32 colorkey;
        printf("Loading bit map %s %d...\n",map_name,tran);
        temp = SDL_LoadBMP(map_name);
        if (temp == NULL){
                printf("Unable to load bitmap: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                SDL_FreeSurface(temp);
                exit(0);
        }else{
                map = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
                colorkey = SDL_MapRGB( map -> format, 132, 0, 12);
                if ( tran==1 ) SDL_SetColorKey( map, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, colorkey );
                SDL_FreeSurface(temp);
        }
                return map;
 }
```

file2.c

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern SDL_Surface **brickim;/*brings brickim to this function*/

void initialize_balls()
{
      printf("Into initialization :)\n ");
    printf("%d \n",brickim[0]->w); /***returns segmentation fault***/
}
```

> ```
> $./kuranes
> Loading bit map brick1.bmp 1...
> level image:) 100 (x10 times)
> Into initialization :)
> Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
> ```

Everything was running ok when I used a single `SDL_Surface` compiled with gcc but I need to do it dynamically. I think something very basic is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here. You declare a global brickim, this will be what the extern declaration finds. You then, in load_level, declare a *local* brickim variable. You *can* declare a variable with the same name in different scopes, but the global brickim will not be used within load_level, the local one will. Therefore, while you do malloc into the *local* brickim, you don't ever assign into the global brickim - and therefore if you access it via extern, it will be NULL and you'll segfault.

```
SDL_Surface **brickim; /*as global*/
SDL_Surface* load_map(char *map_name , int tran );

void load_level(int stage){
int n;
SDL_Surface **brickim=( SDL_Surface **)malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface)*input.N);
    for (n=0;n < input.N;n++){
        **brickim[n]=load_map("brick1.bmp",1); /*load SDL_Surfaces*/**
        printf("%d\n",brickim[n]->w);  /***access succesfully (returns 100 N times)***/
        }
...
}}
```

**edit:** you might want to check that whole allocation in general. I'm not familiar with the SDL_Surface struct, but i assume it's *not* a pointer type (it's a generic struct). Your allocation is actually allocating N structures, but you're casting as if you're allocating N *pointers* to SDL_Surface structures. Don't cast malloc.

If you want N SDL_Surface structures, you only need to have:

```
SDL_Surface * brickim = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface) * N)
```

If you want N pointers to SDL_Surface structures, you would need:

```
SDL_Surface ** brickim = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface *) * N)
for( i = 0; i < N; i++){
   // you've only allocated an array of pointers so far, you now need
   // allocate N structures  
   brickim[0] = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface));
}
```

Comment: Hi Walter thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the two options didn't work. the first one does not compile due to malloc created a simple struct. In my understanding, a simple SDL surface must be declared as SDL_Surface *s, so I think it means it's a pointer struct, because at the end it should be used as s->w. The second option is new for me but I tryed and I got the same segmentation fault. If I use extern SDL_Surface **brickim  ocurrs the same segdefault or if I use SDL_Surface *brickim it does not compile.

Comment: This how my code looks for the second option:
`SDL_Surface **brickim;
SDL_Surface ** brickim=malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface*)*input.N);
for (n=0;n < input.N;n++) {
      brickim[n] = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface));
      brickim[n]=load_map("brick1.bmp",1);
      printf("level image:) %d \n",brickim[n]->w);
}` 
it gives Segmentation default in the same place.

Comment: Don't forget to read the first part of my answer. In your load_level function you're redeclaring brickim when you write `SDL_Surface ** brickim = ...`. You *can* declare variables with the same name in different scopes, you'll access the first variable of that name in the most recent scope, see this trivial example: https://gist.github.com/casba/086ed268a4fae553abbe.

You still seem to be declaring a local brickim variable in your load_level function, which means your global brickim is NEVER set, meaning the other source file using the extern declaration is ref'ing the never-set global brickim

Comment: Ok. I understand that there is a redeclaration with malloc in load_level and converted to local variable. But there is any way to allocate in a global scope?. This is what I want in order to be used by other functions. The order of this two function in my main function is as follows: `level(1); initialize_balls();`.

Comment: Yes, you simply declare the variable in the global scope, then reference it locally. All you need to do is *not* write the type information again.

`int i = 0; // global

void access_global() {
 i = 5; // will look in the global scope, note i don't redeclare, just access
}
`

Comment: Ok I think you were right. The next combination worked for me. file1: `SDL_Surface **brickim; brickim=malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface)*input.N); /*Allocates globally*/  for (n=0;n < input.N;n++) brickim[n]=load_map("brick1.bmp",1);` meanwhile in file2: `extern SDL_Surface **brickim; void initialization_brick(){
 w=brickim[0]->w;} /*Correct access to global brickim*/`. Thanks a lot :)